# Просмотр файлов с Яндекс Диска через WebDAV при помощи Sardine

Tags: java, файлы, webdav, яндекс-диск

Вообще захотелось написать приложения для взаимодействия с Яндекс Диском, нашел код, который работает при помощи Java DAV library (Sardine). Скачал библиотеку, запустил проверочный код(должен выводить список файлов на диске):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String URL = "https://webdav.yandex.ru/";  
    String login = "some login";  
    String pswd = "some password"; 

    Sardine sardine = SardineFactory.begin(login, pswd);  
  
    for (DavResource res : sardine.getResources(URL)) {  
        System.out.println(res.getName());  
    }  
}
```

И получил вот это:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/RedirectStrategy
    at com.github.sardine.SardineFactory.begin(SardineFactory.java:45)
    at com.github.sardine.SardineFactory.begin(SardineFactory.java:35)
    at Disk.main(Disk.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.RedirectStrategy
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 8 more
```

Я так понял, что проекту не хватает `org/apache/http/client/RedirectStrategy`, я и это скачал, добавил в `Classpath`, и ничего, все тоже самое.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как поступить в данной ситуации?

Comment: А как Вы подключали библиотеку?

Comment: Я пользуюсь Intellij Idea 16, там библиотеки подключаются в настройках проекта, т.е. ничего в консоль вводить не нужно

Comment: Я сейчас подключил данную библиотеку через `maven` и при выполнении Вашего кода получил ошибку авторизации (что вполне понятно). Других ошибок не было.

Comment: хм, странно, а вы не могли бы скинуть на всякий случай ссылку на то место, где вы загрузили библиотеку, вдруг я кривую какую то скачал

Comment: http://savepic.ru/11938850.jpg

Comment: Ура, получилось, видимо проблема была все же в скачанной мною библиотеке, сейчас все работает как и должно. Большое вам спасибо!!!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте библиотеку следующим образом:

File – Project Structure – Libraries – Add – From Maven – `com.github.lookfirst:sardine:5.7`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]